# Alert sounds occasionally getting stuck in loop

Tags: macos, catalina, alert

Every once in a while when I get a standard notification alert sound — this has happened a few times with the 'trash emptied' sound, and once or twice with the 'new mail arrived' sound — the sound gets stuck in a half-second repeating loop. I can clear it by forcing the machine to produce a *new* alert sound, but otherwise it seems to go on indefinitely.

This problem has only started since I upgraded to Catalina, on a 2019 MacBook Pro, and it's inconsistent: it happens about twice a month, maybe. I was just curious if anyone had any insights before I pull out the big guns (like a PRAM or SMC reset).

Comment: NVRAM & SMC resets aren't 'big guns', they're hardly even catapults. They have become 'go-to' memes in the same way as 'clear cache' & 'reinstall' have. They are useful in certain circumstances, but this doesn't feel like one of them.

Comment: @Tetsujin: forgive my tendency to exaggerate... 